# How to have a global variable that has been read from a list that has filenames in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, scripting-language

I have one txt file that has bunch of class names.

I would like to read those class names line by line in bash script and assign that value to a variable to use it globally in another command in the script.

```
FILES="files.txt"

for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
  cat $f
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `files.txt` is a list of the class files, one class per line?

```
while read class
do : whatver you need with $class
done < files.txt
```

If you have more than one file of classes, use an array.
Don't make it all caps.

```
file_list=( files.txt other.txt ) # put several as needed
for f in "${file_list[@]}" # use proper quoting
do : processing $f # set -x for these to log to stderr
   while read class
   do : whatver you need with $class
   done < "$f"
done
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer so when i add additional command with the need of $class attribute variable i should just use it in de "do" part right? I cant use after done?

Comment: The `$class` variable's value will not persist past the loop, but you could set `foo=$class` inside the loop and `$foo` would still remain afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each line in your files contain only a class name, this should do it :

```
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  while read class
  do 
    <something with "$class" >
  done < $f
done
```

Comment: I have one file that contains several File Paths.. I think this does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1

```
FILES="files.txt" 
cat $FILES | while read class
do
   echo $class  # Do something with $class
done
```

Example 2, as commented by Paul Hodges

```
FILES="files.txt"
while read class
do
   echo $class  # Do something with $class
done < $FILES
```

Comment: I have one file that contains several File Paths.. I think this does not work for me @PaulHodges